# Need to convert VB 6 forms to Html forms

Tags: html, forms, vb6, vb6-migration

We have developed a standalone application using visual basic 6. 
Now we are changing the standalone application to web application. 
Is there any way to convert VB6 forms into plain HTML forms so that my work will be reduced alot. 
please give your suggestions.

**Edit:** I am new to VB6 and .net technology

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't even *think* about "converting". It's not just a "conversion" process. The entire paradigm is different between web applications and desktop applications. They're just totally different.

ASP.NET web forms try to make the differences less apparent. However, the differences are still there, and are still huge.

What you should do is separate your business logic from your forms logic in your VB6 application. You will then be more easily able to convert the business logic into .NET business logic. You'll still need to create equivalent forms, but the logic will be the same.

Comment: +1. If you move the VB6 business logic into separate DLLs, you can even use those DLLs unchanged from an ASP.Net frontend. You could then migrate the DLLs to .Net piecemeal as necessary.

Comment: If you do that you can even use Classic ASP or any other server-side COM-capable environment.  No need for .Net unless you choose to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply convert VB6  form to html, there is some website which provides this conversion.. but this will increase your work more

refer - [VB to HTML convertor](http://www.ostrosoft.com/vb/VBtoHTML_in.asp)

Comment: That link made me lol. I even uploaded a file to see what it would convert it to. I was underwhelmed when the result was the exact same code I uploaded!

Comment: ha ha ha :) i was also disappointed the same! how can any one make such websites and create problems... Thats the reason i said 'this will increase your work more' :)

Comment: @Matt The point of the website is to convert VB6 code to HTML, so that you can post it on your website as a sample.  I used it to use this link back in the 90s.